# Step-by-step conversion to module-based folder structure for zend project

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view

I'm looking for a step-by-step explanation on how to go from the normal folder structure on the left where the `application` folder contains `models,views,controllers`, to the module-based folder structure on the right where `application` contains a `modules` folder which contains the individual modules with their own `models,views,controllers`.

I say "conversion" because I don't think zend lets us create projects using the module architecture from the start, but if it did, that would be swell and would remove the need to make these folder structure changes manually.

[image: http://img375.imageshack.us/img375/5582/foldersboth.jpg]

**Here's my experience so far**

- When I create a module `zf create module product`, the modules folder is generated and a folder `product` is generated inside it and the `views,controllers,models` for that module are also generated.
- But I also need to move the main `views,controllers,models` to a `modules/default` folder of their own. If I create that folder manually and move the main `views,models,controllers` there, I get a bug when trying to add new controllers to that `default` module. The bug is that it **re-generates** the main (now missing) `views,controllers,models` in `application` and inserts that new controller in `application/controllers/newcont` because it doesn't recognize that the default controllers folder has been moved manually to `application/modules/default/controllers/`.
- So my solution to that has been to `zf create module default` then copy the main `views,models,controllers` there. It ends up looking the same but somehow the `zf create module` method makes a difference. When I do it this way, new controllers get added correctly into `application/modules/default/controllers` and not `application/controllers`

Half the problem solved. But when I try to view the application, I don't see anything from `index/index` view. I don't get any errors either, but I see nothing. I suspect that it's because the application doesn't know that the `index/index` view has moved.

- This used to be located at `application/views/scripts/index/index.phtml`
- but is now located at `application/modules/default/views/scripts/index/index.phtml`

I'm guessing I need to make changes to application.ini or to bootstrap.php or some other location. So what exactly are the steps to get this thing done smoothly and get it working? I'm using the latest ZF 1.10.8. Please start from create a new zend project so there's no confusion on the exact steps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's what I did to try and follow your example (from scratch):

```
$ zf create project .
$ zf create module product
$ zf create module default
```

I then moved `controllers`, `models` and `views` from `./application` to `./application/modules`.

Next I opened up application.ini, and **replaced** this line (which tells ZF where to find controllers in a non-modular app):

```
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
```

with:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```

which tells ZF where to find modules.

I then manually created an index controller for the product module so I could test that this worked, which it did. I then hit http://localhost/index/index to see if the default module index action still worked, it didn't, instead I got the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller class ("Default_ErrorController")' in ...

it sounds like this is where you got to.

There are two ways to fix this error, and the documentation is quite misleading (possibly even wrong). It [states](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.modular.html):

> Note that in the default module, controllers do not need a namespace prefix. Thus, in the example above, the controllers in the default module do not need a prefix of 'Default_' -- they are simply dispatched according to their base controller name: 'IndexController' and 'FooController'. A namespace prefix is used in all other modules, however.

but clearly the error above indicates that ZF is looking for an ErrorController class called Default_ErrorController. To fix this you can do one of two things:

- Change the class names of application/modules/default/controllers/IndexController.php from `IndexController` to `Default_IndexController`, and application/modules/default/controllers/ErrorController.php from `ErrorController` to `Default_ErrorController`
- Or remove this line:

  resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = "1"

from application.ini. This line tells ZF to use the 'Default_' namespace on the default module classes, so without it it will just look for 'IndexController'. I went for the latter option, and http://localhost/index/index then worked as expected.

In your case you said you got a blank page at /index/index, which means either:

- You have a different problem
- You have errors disabled in development mode
- You are running in production mode where errors are disabled by default (most likely)

to check the last option, open application.ini and *temporarily* change `phpSettings.display_errors` from 0 to 1 in the production section. If you then get the same error I had above, hopefully you'll be able to get everything working.

I hope this is helpful. All I can say is don't get too reliant on Zend_Tool for management of your app - it can't do everything, and often it's easier to manually move things around than to try and do everything via. the zf command; particularly when restructuring.

Comment: Thanks Tim, More than helpful, totally solved my problem. I'll start the bounty when the system lets me (I think 2 days or something) and choose this answer then.

Comment: +1 for the excellent answer, especially for `prefixDefaultModule`

Comment: Sorry for the late bounty. The system required that I wait 23 hours from the time I started the bounty before I could assign it + had to wait 2 days after posting the question to start the bounty. Stupid bounty system.

Answer (score 1):

Well I dev in Netbeans IDE.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Zjn.jpg

Im a newbie :P ( need 10 points)

Each Bootstrap should have :

```
<?php 
// Public_Bootstrap replace for Blog_Bootstrap or Administrator_Bootstrap
// well its for me
class Public_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {

}
```

Main Bootstrap:

```
<?php
    class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap {

       protected function _initAutoLoad() {

          $modLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(
                    array(
                        'namespace' => '',
                        'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/public'
                    )
          );        

          return $modLoader;
       }
       public function _initViewHelpers() {

          $this->bootstrap(array('frontcontroller', 'view'));
          $view = $this->getResource('view');
          $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
          $view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8")
            ->appendName("description", "Some description");
     }
  }
```

application.ini :

```
[production]
resources.modules[] =
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0 
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php" 
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap" 
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.defaultmodule = "public" 
resources.frontController.prefixDefaultModule = true  

resources.view[] = 

resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true 
resources.db.params.host ="localhost"
resources.db.params.username ="yourUser"
resources.db.params.password ="yourPassword"
resources.db.params.dbname ="DBName"
```

My bootstrap have more code, including plugings.